# Get all user defined objects from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying how to get all user defined objects (tables, views, store procedures) but not the system ones.

I'm playing with ***sys.objects*** and ***sys.all_objects*** where I've found only one flag - ***is_ms_shipped*** but looking for something more accurate to achieve what I want.

Comment: What about that is inaccurate?

Comment: Honestly, not sure.

Comment: The [SMO API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.issystemobject?view=sqlserver-2016) has a `IsSystemObject` boolean property on objects but I have a feeling it is looking at `is_ms_shipped`